# Aligning on a Word

Tags: assembly

```
.data
myBytes BYTE 10h,20h,30h,40h
myWords WORD 3 DUP(?),2000h
myString BYTE "ABCDE"
```

If we were to declare our variables as such, would myBytes, the very first declaration, be aligned at an offset that is optimal for the CPU (which is on a word)?

Answer (score 0):

No, usually, you have to use meta assembler like .align to force correct allignment. Check your assemblers manual